# Apache 2.4 how to Require valid-user only for specific hosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, basic-authentication, server-configuration

I want to tell Apache 2.4.9 to require valid-user if host is dev.example.com or test.example.com. This doesn't work:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Speak, friend, and enter."
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /sites/example/conf/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^dev\.example\.com$ env_is_protected
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^test\.example\.com$ env_is_protected
Require valid-user
Require not env env_is_protected
```

It causes a server error; evidently `not env` is not valid [contrary to the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html#blocking-of-robots).

In the following examples, the first five lines are always the same as in the first example.

This doesn't work:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^dev\.example\.com$ env_is_protected
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^test\.example\.com$ env_is_protected
<RequireAny>
    Require valid-user
    <RequireNone>
        Require env env_is_protected
    </RequireNone>
</RequireAny>
```

It causes a server error. The [documentation explains](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireany):

> Because negated authorization directives are unable to return a
>   successful result, they can not significantly influence the result of
>   <RequireAny> directive. (At most they could cause the directive to
>   fail in the case where they failed and all other directives returned a
>   neutral value.) Therefore negated authorization directives are not
>   permitted within a <RequireAny> directive.

This doesn't work:

```
SetEnv env_is_unprotected 1
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^dev\.example\.com$ !env_is_unprotected
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^test\.example\.com$ !env_is_unprotected
Require valid-user
Require env env_is_unprotected
```

The documentation [explains about SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

> The internal environment variables set by this directive are set after
>   most early request processing directives are run, such as access
>   control and URI-to-filename mapping. If the environment variable
>   you're setting is meant as input into this early phase of processing
>   such as the RewriteRule directive, you should instead set the
>   environment variable with SetEnvIf.

This works:

```
SetEnvIf Host . env_is_unprotected
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^dev\.example\.com$ !env_is_unprotected
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^test\.example\.com$ !env_is_unprotected
Require valid-user
Require env env_is_unprotected
```

This looks like a hack and takes hours to figure out. Have I failed to discover the *proper* way of accomplishing my very simple purpose? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it. 
(Using Cj Case's nice citation as a comment to explain details. :D )

```
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST ^dev\.example\.com$ env_is_protected
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST ^test\.example\.com$ env_is_protected
<RequireAny>
    <RequireAll>
        # when the Require directive is negated it can only fail or return a neutral result, 
        # and therefore may never independently authorize a request
        # (reason why we need an additional "all granted" here!)
        Require all granted
        Require not env env_is_protected
    </RequireAll>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Speak, friend, and enter."
    AuthUserFile /sites/example/conf/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only able to use the "not" directive on a RequireAll block and not as an authentication directive.

> The result of the Require directive may be negated through the use of the not option. As with the other negated authorization directive , when the Require directive is negated it can only fail or return a neutral result, and therefore may never independently authorize a request.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

This would probably work:

```
<Directory /your/protected/directory/>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Speak, friend, and enter."
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /sites/example/conf/.htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null

  SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^dev\.example\.com$ env_is_protected
  SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^test\.example\.com$ env_is_protected

  <RequireAll>
    Require valid-user
    Require not env env_is_protected
  </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

Comment: `not env` is invalid, the question explicitly says that.

Comment: Should be valid inside a RequireAll block as far as I can tell.

Comment: I suspect that this is the right answer, but I haven't accepted it yet because I haven't gotten around to testing it yet. It's on my to-do list, sorry to be so slow.